# Is it appropriate to link a (helpful) person in comments?

Tags: discussion

Looked for this question here, and saw suggestions for implementation, but not anything that directly answers the question "Is it appropriate to thank someone by name in the comments of an answer?"

In my specific case the area where (s)he was help is pending deletion.

I did so by doing this `[Name](link_to_profile/batch)` with a short attribution.

*update*: As requested, here are... **[The Specifics](https://superuser.com/a/499663/169719)**

And here is the 'frozen in time' graphic proof...

[image]

Comment: It's not inappropriate, but is it necessary?

Comment: That is a good question. I would say no, otherwise it would be documented in the FAQ to help ensure the courtesy. But habitually doing so would be very annoying. Kind of like how we disregard normal greetings in IRC and just ask the question, rather than asking to ask.)  I definitely see the 'danger' though.  And I did consider not saying 'thanks' because of this.

Comment: A bit more specific, please? Is this a question you asked and have the ability to accept an answer on? Is this a comment you're leaving under answers you didn't accept? Is this meant for answers on questions other people asked?

Comment: Tim, actually it was after requesting my answer be deleted as a result of some fleshing out what it is we were looking for.  I posted another answer, as a result.  But due to the requested deletion of my answer in the first place, his comments would eventually be deleted with the answer, and so his comments and the 'story' behind the answer eventually would not be told.  (I know realize that I probably should have done a complete overhauling edit on my original poor answer to improve it.)  [The Specifics](http://superuser.com/a/499663/169719)

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer update it with the new answer and undelete it? That way the story behind will remain there.

Comment: What @Starx said. +1 to that.

Comment: I didn't know I was allowed to do that without voting it back up.  I will try to do that!  But then I delete the already created other answer?  Is it best to leave it as is and remember this lesson for next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to modify the answer and leave the discussion history intact to show any help you got to get there, thus alleviating the need to have a 'thanks' comment.